# Is there a setting with git to allow a clone to use http on one OS and ssh on another?

Tags: windows, git, svn, macos

**Short Question**
Is there a setting with git to allow a clone to use http on one OS and ssh on another?  For an exact usage: Is possible to use http protocol (cloned in Windows) on Mac OS X terminal which typically uses SSH connections

**Background**
I have a Macbook Pro that I dual boot with Mac OS X and Windows 7.  I have a shared express-34 card that I store all of my repositories / working directories on.  I use this so I can work from the Mac side or Windows side seamlessly (until now).  At this point, I am unable to commit / update any changes from repositories I clone / checkout from Windows.  It's worth noting that git repos that I clone from Mac, work fine in Windows, just not the other way around.

**System Information**
Windows 7:
Tortoise git and Tortoise SVN

OS X:
homebrew installed git and SVN

**Update**
I am now sharing a single SSH checkout (at the project level) on both Mac OS X Lion and Windows 7.  This is working when I am booted natively into Win 7 as well as when it is virtualized inside of Lion.

Comment: Dunno why this got downvoted. Seems like a pretty reasonable thing to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking I don't think this is possible using the same [remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) name.  A particular remote is always defined by a URL which specifies the protocol.  However you can add a new remote with a different URL which species a different protocol.

A problem with doing this is that you'll have the same remote with two different names in the same repository. This means that all remote branches (origin/master etc.) will be duplicated and will get out of sync which will cause problems with any git behavior that depends on branch names instead of SHA hashes.

For example, suppose you have a remote named 'windows' that specifies http and a remote name 'mac' which specifies ssh.  Suppose your repository gets behind your remote you update in OSX using git fetch/merge now mac/master is up to date but windows/master is not.  This may not be a big deal to you but it does mean [tracking branches](http://book.git-scm.com/4_tracking_branches.html) and other branch name dependent behavior may not work as you expect.

Comment: This type of behavior is what I was afraid of, but could not confirm.

Comment: Yeah I would look at getting SSH working on Windows.  I've never used git in Windows but a few quick google searchs turned up a lot of hits for configuring tortiesgit with SSH. It also looks like msysgit comes with an SSH package built in.

Comment: Found the same Google hits for tortoise.  I am still learning git, soon enough I will be using the CLI for msysgit.

Comment: Turns out I was over complicating Tortoise SVN's SSH functionality.  It's as easy as running pagent with your private key loaded...  It functions just like TortoiseGIT.